# Sumiu a caixa de aviso ao dar voto contra

Tags: suporte, voto-contra

Até certo tempo atrás tínhamos uma caixa que avisava quando dávamos um voto contra, nos incentivando a dar uma explicação do por que dele. Entretanto hoje me dei conta de que essa caixinha não está mais aparecendo.

A caixa é similar a essa do Meta SE:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que foi a implementação do pedido de [novo-recurso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/novo-recurso) na pergunta [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/229289).

Nos demais sites da rede SE a caixa continua aparecendo, só sumiu aqui no SOPT, tanto no site principal quanto no Meta.

Comment: Engraçado, pra mim ela continua aparecendo...

Comment: Talvez ela suma para quem já tem X+ pontos de reputação.

Comment: @bfavaretto pode ser! Vou pesquisar.

Comment: "edit: this is now implemented and live for users with reputation below 2000. It is shown on every downvote until you get to 2k." http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2373/218708

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Como diz [nesta resposta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2373/218708) a funcionalidade está implementada para usuários com reputação inferior a 2000 (2k).